# Is there a jquery marquee plugin/script that works with images of different width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need a jQuery marquee plugin/script that works with images of different widths, lets say first image is 130px wide and second image is 50px width, and third is 250px and so on.

I need it to be continous, responsive and easy to setup, I've tryied width crawler.js and it doesn't work on my site.

Thanks in advance and forgive the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/ ?
It is

- Easy to set up
- Continuous

You can make it responsive with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for, I just made the container responsive and everything runs just fine. :D